# How to accept input in a single line using cobra library in Go

Tags: go, input, go-cobra

I am writing a code in go language using cobra, currently the input Im giving is :

```
 Calc add 
           Enter the Number of inputs
           2
           Enter the Numbers
           2
           4
 Output: Sum is : 6
```

In this those who are familiar with cobra, Calc is my project and add is the command Im using,I want the input to be given as `Calc add N2 2 4`( in a single line) and the output should be displayed, where N is a variable that identifies the Number of inputs and 2 4 are the numbers to be added.

CODE FOR THE ADD COMMAND:

```
package cmd

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
)

// addCmd represents the add command
var addCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "add",
    Short: "Addition value of given Numbers",

    Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
        length := 0
    fmt.Println("Enter the number of inputs")
    fmt.Scanln(&length)
    fmt.Println("Enter the inputs")
    numbers := make([]int, length)
    for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
        fmt.Scanln(&numbers[i])
    }
      fmt.Println(numbers)

      sum:=0

for _, numbers := range numbers {

sum += numbers

}

fmt.Println("The Sum :",sum)


 },
}

func init() {
    RootCmd.AddCommand(addCmd)


}
```

P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will fulfill your purpose. Take your number in a flag `--input`. Give other numbers to add as arguments.

```
func NewCmd() *cobra.Command {
    var input int
    c := &cobra.Command{
        Use:   "add",
        Short: "Addition value of given Numbers",

        Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
            if len(args) != input {
                fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("You need to provide %v number to sum up", input))
                os.Exit(1)
            }
            numbers := make([]int, input)
            for i := 0; i < input; i++ {
                num, _ := strconv.Atoi(args[i])
                numbers[i] = num
            }
            sum := 0
            for _, numbers := range numbers {
                sum += numbers
            }
            fmt.Println("The Sum :", sum)
        },
    }
    c.Flags().IntVar(&input, "input", 0, "Number of input")
    return c
}

func init() {
    cmd := NewCmd()
    RootCmd.AddCommand(cmd)
}
```

Input:

```
Calc add --input=3 6 3 6
```

Output:
    The Sum : 15

Comment: shows an error saying unknown flag, cant understand why.@AerofoilKite

Comment: @Manu, are you still getting that error.. You need to pass flag --input

Comment: I fixed it. @AerofoilKite

Comment: what if I don't want to mention the flag name while taking the input.
for eg: calc  -a 1 2 3 4 ( a for addition) @AerofoilKite

Comment: I didnt quiet understand what you meant.I have tried without using the flag name and without the hi-fen before the command.But I want the hi-fen before the command and exactly in the same format.Can You Help Me Out.